# Is it okay to use MySQL Workbench with MariaDB?

Tags: mariadb, mysql-workbench

**Workbench 8** gives me a warning when connecting to **MariaDB**, but it appears to work fine. Since MariaDB is based on MySQL, would it be a problem to keep using it?

[image: connection warning]

Comment: VtC since any answers now may very well be invalid in the future due to developmental changes between MySQL / MariaDB. The warning the app gives is fairly self explanatory.

Comment: Generally yes, but watch out.  Workbench likes to include the `VISIBLE` that MariaDB does not [yet] implement.

Answer (score 2):

This warning is shown for any other but the supported MySQL versions (at the time being these are 5.6, 5.7 and 8.0). The application uses language features and other resources that may or may not work with other servers. It's actually not tested, which is the main reason why this warning comes up.

MariaDB might be based on MySQL, but over time it more and more diverts from its root and it's very likely that there is an increasing number of incompatibilities.